# Form not valid with ordered combo

Tags: forms, symfony, entity, query-builder

i have a form with two collections. Those widgets are rendered as combos.
When i config a query builder in a combo, for display the data ordered, the form submission fails with null values. But, when i skip the order, the form submit ok.
Its my code:

```
$builder
   ->add('alumno', 'entity', array(
      'class' => 'MenuBundle:Alumno',
      'empty_value' => "Seleccione un tutelado."
      /*
      'query_builder' => function(AlumnoRepository $er){
          return $er->getQbOrderBy('apellido', 'ASC');
       }
       */
    ))
    ->add('relacion', 'entity', array(
       'class' => 'MenuBundle:TipoRelacion',
       'empty_value' => "Seleccione un tipo de relación."
    ))
;
```

Any ideas ?.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add **property** attribute:

```
$builder
    ->add('alumno', 'entity', array(
     'class' => 'MenuBundle:Alumno',
     'empty_value' => "Seleccione un tutelado.",
     'property'=>'youPropertyName',
     ))
     ->add('relacion', 'entity', array(
     'class' => 'MenuBundle:TipoRelacion',
     'empty_value' => "Seleccione un tipo de relación.",
    'property'=>'youPropertyName',
   ))
   ;
```